# Multiple clients listening to a PostgreSQL notification

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL's LISTEN/NOTIFY feature to listen when a row changes.

For that I use a PHP script to listen to a specific channel.

As I want to maintain the high availability of this notification, is it possible to have more than one client listening to the same channel and PostgreSQL distribute a notification to each client (similarly to Rabbit) or will both clients always receive the same notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All listeners will get notified.

You can have more than one listener and use other synchronization methods to ensure that only one of them processes the task, for example an [advisory lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) or a queue table.